# Advanced counting

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to count how many cells that have a value given that a corresponding cell in another column has the value x. Any good ideas how to get this done? The value given if one wanted to count how many cells in A has a value given that the corresponding cell in B has an x on the dataset on the image under is **4**

[image: Excel image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A12))*(B1:B12="x"))
```

This resolves as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})*(B1:B12="x"))

=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*(B1:B12="x"))

=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})

=SUMPRODUCT({1;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0})
```

Trues are 1 and Falses are zero when forced to be a number (like when you multiply them).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$12);0;1)*IF($B$1:$B$12="x";1;0))
```

You may have to validate like an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) with `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`

Comment: No, you don't need to make SUMPRODUCT an array formula, it takes care of that internally, so no brackets needed either.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Thanks, i'm always wondering when using SUMPRODUCT if it needs to be validated as an array formula

Comment: Actually, it's not working, I think ISBLANK doesn't like the array.  I also tried to make it an array formula anyway and that didn't work either.

Comment: Not sure what's up, but I got this to work: =SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$7<>""),--($B$1:$B$7="x")).